# Nginx config to access same IP but different port?

Tags: nginx

I have one virtual IP (keepalived IP z.z.z.z) .I am creating 2 different webpages and want to access it using this virtual ip via nginx . I read that I can achieve it with different ports but I do not want to show the port . So what I want is when I hit x.x.x.x it should ask for username and password and when I enter it should take me to the respective webpage .

my current config file for 1st web page

```
upstream kibana {
        server x.x.x.x:30001;
        server y.y.y.y:30001;
        }
        server {
                listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name z.z.z.z;
        location / {
                auth_basic      "protect kibana";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.user;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://kibana;
                }
        }
```

My Edited Conf file

```
upstream kibana {
        server x.x.x.x:30001;
        server y.y.y.y:30001;
        }
upstream kibana2 {
        server x.x.x.x:30002;
        server y.y.y.y:30002;
        }

        server {
                listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name z.z.z.z;
        location / {
                auth_basic      "protect kibana";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.user;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://kibana;
                }
        }
```

As I am using another upstream that is kibana 2 , so how I need to add another server stenza ?

Regards
VG

Comment: So no password for y.y.y.y?

Comment: In my opinion this really isn't a question for SO, but have you considered using name based virtual hosting (`server_name` directives)?

Comment: so x.x.x.x and y.y.y.y are my web servers which is being load balanced by Nginx , so I have 2 nginx also which i am load balancing by keepalived IP z.z.z.z. I want to hit to z.z.z.z only it should ask for user name and password now if the used is vg1 it should open x.x.x.x:3001 or y.y.y.y:3001 and if user is vg2 then it should open x.x.x.x:3002, or y.y.y.y:3002

Comment: @TarunLalwani , Password will only appear when I hit z.z.z.z IP

Comment: what is vg1 and vg2? Different virtual host names?

Comment: @TarunLalwani :-  So vg1 and Vg2 are the user names . So Vg1 should restricted to  proxy_pass http://kibana and vg2 user should be restricted to proxy_pass http://kibana2